# 1.7.10 Minecraft Forge Compiling Error

Tags: minecraft

```
[
{
 "MODID": "ms",
 "name": "More Stuff",

 "description": "This adds more items to minecraft",

"version": "${1.0}",

"mc_version": "${1.7.10}",

"url": "",

"updateUrl": "",

"authorList": ["Sean Blumenfeld"],

"credits": "Sean Blumenfeld",

"logoFile": "",

"screenshots": [],

"dependencies": []
}
]
```

When I run the sh gradlew build command in terminal I get the following out put:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processResources'.

  > Could not copy file '/Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/Java Review/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/src/main/resources/mcmod.info' to '/Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/Java Review/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/build/resources/main/mcmod.info'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I have no clue what this means or what I did wrong. If you can help me figure it out, I would greatly appreciate it.

here is the --stacktrace output looks like:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processResources'.

  > Could not copy file '/Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/JavaReview/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/src/main/resources/mcmod.info' to '/Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/JavaReview/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/build/resources/main/mcmod.info'.
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':processResources'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:296)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:105)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:85)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy file '/Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/JavaReview/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/src/main/resources/mcmod.info' to '/Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/JavaReview/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/build/resources/main/mcmod.info'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:79)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:102)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction$FileCopyDetailsInternalAction.processFile(FileCopyAction.java:44)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:65)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:60)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:60)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:44)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:157)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:125)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:115)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:96)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:37)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:24)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:498)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:500)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:500)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:322)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DelegatingCopySpecInternal.walk(DelegatingCopySpecInternal.java:206)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:44)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:56)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction.execute(FileCopyAction.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask.copy(AbstractCopyTask.java:83)
  at org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.copy(ProcessResources.java:33)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:570)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:553)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
  ... 47 more
  Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
  SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 7: unexpected token: 10 @ line 7, column 27.
   \"mc_version\": \"${1.7.10}\",
                           ^

1 error

```
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:90)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:84)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ChainingTransformer.transform(ChainingTransformer.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.open(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyFile(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:74)
... 82 more
```

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.389 secs

Comment: Try running with --stacktrace or --info or --debug to get more information.

Comment: Does the /Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/Java Review/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/build/resources/main/ directory exist?  It should be but if not try creating it.  I would think a build process would have steps to build the intermediate directories, so maybe you are missing a step?  It could also be permissions, make sure you are able to create the build directory.

Comment: yes it does exist however the file is: /Users/seanblumenfeld/Desktop/Java\ Review/mod/forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src/build/resources/main/.

Comment: see above for the stack trace out put

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of the stack trace:

> Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed: SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 7: unexpected token: 10 @ line 7, column 27. \"mc_version\": \"${1.7.10}\", ^

It specifies that the `mc_version` line in your `mcmod.info` can't be parsed. If you look at the [forge docs](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/structuring/#the-mcmodinfo-file) you will see the name of the variable is `mcversion`, not `mc_version`. Hopefully changing the name of the variable should solve the error.